# Application icon removed from home screen on upgrade

Tags: android, icons, upgrade, homescreen

I have an app available on  market. Now I am about to launch an upgrade. Due to some weird reason if I have an icon of old app on "Home screen" and I do upgrade i.e replece, it deletes the homescreen icon. Is that due to change in icon?

OLD:
 `<application android:name="FlirtoApp" 
        android:theme="@style/FlirtoTheme"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">`

NEW:
`<application 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".app.App" android:debuggable="true">`

---

Comment: Have you changed anything in your `AndroidManifest.xml` about the main application activity (other then icon)? If so, please add old version of and new version of that activity defined in `AndroidManifest.xml'

Comment: yes android:name has been changed:
 <application android:name="FlirtoApp" 
     android:theme="@style/FlirtoTheme"
     android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
     android:label="@string/app_name">

 <application 
  android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:name=".app.App" android:debuggable="true">

Comment: I did fix this issue by making <application> android:name exactly the same but my launcher activity is also different so I guess I have to create splashscreen activity with the same name as ol one at the start of app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work around this by using an activity alias in your manifest.

If you need to change the activity associated with the launcher, you can prevent the loss of the home screen icon during an upgrade by declaring the activity that used to hold the LAUNCHER category intent filter as an alias of the first.  Like so:

```
    <activity android:name=".ui.NewLaunchActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <activity-alias android:name="com.domain.app.OldLaunchActivity"
        android:targetActivity=".ui.NewLaunchActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
```

I ran into this issue as well as this did the trick very nicely and the only side effect I've noticed is that ADB no longer auto-launches the application when it does the install from Eclipse.

You can also [take a look at the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read this: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html

Comment: yes that was the issue. I would have consider these things before launching the first version. The first version was pretty basic and everything was in one package. The only workaround I can see is to add a splashscreen at the start same as my first version